# Movemail report error "cannot open: Invalid reply from the remote host"

Tags: mail

I tried to employ movemail upon imap as

```
movemail imap://abst.proc.do@imap.qq.com:993 nivfomuguessme ~/RMAIL
```

and alternatively

```
movemail imap://abst.proc.do:nivfoguessmeii@imap.qq.com:993 ~/RMAIL
```

But report error:

```
movemail: mailbox `imap://abst.proc.do:***@imap.qq.com:993': cannot open: Invalid reply from the remote host
movemail: mailbox `imap://abst.proc.do@imap.qq.com:993': cannot open: Invalid reply from the remote host
```

What's the problem?

Revised Error:

```
$ movemail -v imap://abst.proc.do@imap.qq.com:993 nivfguessmecii ~/RMAIL
movemail: mu_imap_connect: invalid server response: 
movemail: mailbox `imap://abst.proc.do@imap.qq.com:993': cannot open: Invalid reply from the remote host
```

It works now with error result out of range:

```
$ movemail -vv imaps://abst.proc.do:password@imap.qq.com:993 ~/RMAIL
movemail: number of messages in source mailbox: 52
movemail: cannot append message 13: Numerical result out of range
movemail: number of processed messages: 12
movemail: number of errors: 0 / 1
```

Comment: Rerun this with `-v`as an argument at the beginning of it (`movemail -v ...`) to get the verbose output, which will give us more useful debugging information.  Include sanitized output here.  (Also, if `niv...` is the password well you've just made the Universe able to see your password, so you need to change your passwords.)

Comment: For kicks, try using `imaps://` instead of `imap://` at the beginning.  Does it work?  (Port 993 is usually SSL Required, which is IMAPS)

Comment: wow, it works but still report error result out of range. @ThomasWard

Comment: which is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try without the port number at the end of the url like this:

```
movemail -v imap://abst.proc.do@imap.qq.com nivfguessmecii ~/RMAIL
```

It worked for me.

You might then want to check with --debug-level='mailbox.prot'